# Can I retrieve all the new rows added into the database tables

Tags: sql-server

I want to know is there a query or some SP to retrieve all the new rows added to my tables in my database. I am using SQL Server database.

Comment: New since when? Added during what process? Can you post example code that explains your meaning?

Comment: Do you have a `InsertedOn DATETIME` column in your table(s) ?? Using that, it would be easy to get the rows that have been inserted since any given date...

Comment: you see I am testing my Java application which has around 160 tables. now when i insert a data in my application the data gets stored in different tables in the db. Now to make my testing easier and faster i want to know can i query the databse to return all the tables which had new rows in it. in all my table cols i have a col date which stores the timestamp when a record in added to the tables.hope i made myself clear

Comment: @Oded New i mean just now i.e. today

Comment: Suggestion: 1) take a "snapshot" of your database: either a backup, or use "select into" to "clone" one table to another table.  2) use a "database diff" tool like Red Gate "SQL Compare" (there are several free and commercial products that might fit the bill).  Of course the best thing (as marc_s suggested) is simply *design* your schema to allow querying "what changed".  A "time-date-inserted" column is an obvious candidate...

Comment: @marc_s yes i have a col created and updated which is of type datetime which stores the time when the record was added or updated in the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change Data Capture**

Change data capture is designed to capture insert, update, and delete activity applied to SQL Server tables, and to make the details of the changes available in an easily consumed relational format. The change tables used by change data capture contain columns that mirror the column structure of a tracked source table, along with the metadata needed to understand the changes that have occurred.

Change data capture is available only on the Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation editions of SQL Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645858(v=sql.105)

Comment: how do i query the db after activating the change data capture

Answer (score 2):

**Configuring and Managing Change Tracking**

Change tracking in SQL Server 2008 enables applications to obtain only changes that have been made to the user tables, along with the information about those changes. With change tracking integrated into SQL Server, complicated custom change tracking solutions no longer have to be developed.

Change tracking is an important building block for applications that synchronize and replicate data in scenarios in which end-to-end replication solutions do not work and a custom solution is required. For example, a scenario that requires synchronizing data with data stores that are not SQL Server databases or in which the store schemas are very different.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964713(v=sql.105).aspx